How Do I Use AWS Amplify GraphQL Mutations on Nextjs Pages/API Routes?
I've taken the code examples from the AWS Amplify V6 docs.
My goal is to be able to update anyone's Dynamodb record via this backend function.
amplifyServerUtils.ts:
import { createServerRunner } from "@aws-amplify/adapter-nextjs";
import config from "@/src/aws-exports";

export const { runWithAmplifyServerContext } = createServerRunner({
  config
});

pages/api/test.js:
import { fetchAuthSession } from "aws-amplify/auth/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { runWithAmplifyServerContext } from "@/src/utils/amplifyServerUtils";

const handler = async (request) => {
  const response = NextResponse.next();

  const authenticated = await runWithAmplifyServerContext({
    nextServerContext: { request, response },
    operation: async (contextSpec) => {
      try {
        const session = await fetchAuthSession(contextSpec);
        return session.tokens !== undefined;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
      }
    },
  });

  if (authenticated) {
    return response;
  }

  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/sign-in", request.url));
};

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|sign-in).*)",
  ],
};

export default handler;


